# Идентификация сетевого трафика телеграмм

Tags: ssl, telegram, tls

Необходимо выявлять трафик мессенджера телеграмм. 
Волнует не с точки зрения статистического анализа, а конкретных пробелов в мимикрировании под tls 1.2. 
[Вот](https://telegra.ph/telegram-blocks-wtf-05-26) самая актуальная статья по этой теме. Пробовал руками сравнить нормальный трафик и тг, отличия были очень сильные. Явно не по этим полям теперь начинать сравнивать.
В каком направлении рыть? Изучать всю документацию по работе протокола будет слишком долго...

Comment: Работаете на РосКомНадзор? :)

Comment: нет, студент :)